# Moving files to different folder in various commits using git

Tags: git

This may be a noob question; using Android Studio I made multiple commits creating new files in each commit.

In the last three commits, the new files were placed in wrong directories. Can I go to those commits and place them in right folders with creating new commits?

- Commit 4 --> move /file3 to /sample/file3
- Commit 3 --> move /file2 to /sample/file2
- Commit 2 --> move /file1 to /sample/file1
- Commit 1 --> all fine

Comment: Just move files to correct directories and commit them.

Comment: @wpater so do I delete previous commits after moving the files and creating new commit or is there a way to edit those commits?

Comment: If you don't want to create new commit you can checkout to the one of previous, create changes and then commit. It depends on many conditions in repo. You can also rewrite git tree with new commits but it is not easy if you have more commits after mentioned 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change any existing commit.  But you *can* stop *using* existing commits.

Because commits save the full state of everything (well, everything committed), you can also, in effect, "go back in time" by checking out an older commit.

If you give each commit a unique ID, and draw them out in their sequence, you get something like this:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
```

That is, the latest commit, `D`, remembers the ID of its previous—or *parent*—commit `C`.  Meanwhile `C` remembers its parent, `B`, which remembers its parent `A`.  (If `A` is the very first commit in the repository, it has no parent, since it can't have one.  Otherwise `A` remembers whichever commit came before `A`.)

The way Git *finds* these is that the *name* `master` records the hash ID of the *last* commit.  Since that was `D`, `master` finds `D`.  Since `D` records `C`'s ID, it's `D` itself that finds `C`, which finds `B`, and so on.

So, given all of this, suppose you:

1. Check out commit `A`.  Now `A` is the current commit and you have all files the way they were when you made `A`.
2. Proceed by *copying* all the files from `B`, but then move one of them.  Then you make a new commit that's *just like* `B` except that the file is moved (and the internal saved date for when new-improved-`B` is made is "now" rather than "back then").  You will get a new commit, which we can call `B'`:

   ```
   A--B--C--D
    \
     B'
   ```

   The parent of `B'` is `A`: the backwards-pointing arrow that Git uses to work backwards from each commit to the one that came before, points to commit `A`, just as `B`'s points to commit `A`.  The difference between `B` and `B'` is that you moved the file (and, of course, that `B'` has a different Git hash ID—our letters here stand in for the actual big ugly hash IDs that Git makes up for each new commit).

   There's something missing from this diagram, though: what *name* points to `B'`?  Well, let's not worry about that yet.  Instead, let's move on to...
3. Now, copy `C` to `C'`, renaming one file along the way just as you did when making `B'`.  The parent of `C'` will be `B'`:

   ```
   A--B--C--D
    \
     B'-C'
   ```
4. Repeat for `D` to make `D'`:

   ```
   A--B--C--D
    \
     B'-C'-D'
   ```
5. Have Git write the hash ID of `D'` into the name `master`.  This is the particularly sneaky part: you now have:

   ```
   A--B--C--D   [abandoned]
    \
     B'-C'-D'  <-- master (HEAD)
   ```

   That is, now the name `master` identifies this new-and-improved `D'` instead of the old `D`.

The only problem with doing all this is that if any *other* Git user has a copy of the repository that has the commit sequence `A-B-C-D` in it.  They may build their own commits atop `D`, not atop your new `D'`.  This kind of process will make *their* lives difficult, if they are not ready for it.  So if you *do* have someone else using a clone of this repository, and they *do* have these three commits, consider *not* doing any of this.  But if no one else has the `B-C-D` chain, you're free to replace them with the new-and-improved `B'-C'-D'` chain.  Or, if everyone else involved in this project expects this kind of rewrite, you're still free to do it.  (If there's no one else involved, it's easy to see that of all the other people involved, none of them will object.)

#### OK, so, how can we achieve this rewrite?

The easy way is to use `git rebase -i`.  This *interactive rebase* lets you stop and *change* what will go into each new commit, before it actually makes the commit.  You simply find the actual hash ID of the commit you want to *keep*—in this case, commit `A`—and, while on branch `master`, run:

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

This brings up your favorite editor—or at least, the one you have told Git is your favorite, by setting `core.editor`—on a file with three `pick` commands.  Change each to `edit`, save the file of instructions, and exit the editor.

Git will now proceed to start making `B'` atop `A`, but then stop and let you edit the commit.  Run:

```
git mv file1 sample/file1
```

(first making directory `sample` if needed), then:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

to establish `B'` as the desired result, then:

```
git rebase --continue
```

That will loosely cement `B'` in place and begin the process of copying `C`, then stop, so now you `git mv file2 sample/file2` and `git commit --amend --no-edit` and `git rebase --continue` to move to the copy-D step.  Repeat as before.

Once the updated commits are all done and in place, `git rebase` will do the last step, of yanking the branch name `master` over to point to `D'` instead of `D`.

#### Just for completeness: here's how the intermediate commits work

While Git is building this new replacement `B'-C'-D'` chain, the name that *finds* each of these commits is just `HEAD` itself.  This uses the mode that Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  While it sounds scary, it just means that the special name `HEAD`, that Git requires at all times, is not attached to any *branch name* at all.

For instance, in the middle of the rebase, you have:

```
A--B--C--D  <-- master
 \
  B'  <-- HEAD
```

As more commits get added, you get:

```
A--B--C--D  <-- master
 \
  B'-C'  <-- HEAD
```

and so on.  When `git rebase -i` runs out of instructions—the `pick`s that you changed to `edit`s are the instructions—the rebase is done and Git yanks the name `master` into place, re-attaching `HEAD` to it and getting us the diagram shown in step 5.

Comment: Thanks, I understood a little bit but ended making duplicate commits. So now both the correct file path commit and old one exist. Further more I messed up other files in the process :(

Comment: If, right after a rebase, you're not happy with the result, you can go back to the "abandoned" chain of commits pretty easily. Or, if you haven't finished the rebase, you can use `git rebase --abort` to exit it and return everything to the way it was before you started. To reset after finishing, start with `git log ORIG_HEAD` and make sure you want that; then, if you do, you can use `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` to go back to it. Note that like all `reset --hard` operations, this loses any uncommitted work!

Answer (score -1):

It was suggested in a comment, but it worths an answer.
You can't edit the directory of past commits, 
usually in this situation you should prefer to change the directory and commit the change. unless you really wish to do it in past commit, which then you'll need to revert to the first commit you want to change, and start changing it while recommitting everything.

To revert to a commit you could do `git reset --hard <commit sha1>` or instead of `sha1` use `HEAD~3` for the third commit from the current one.
Then recommit your changes.

If you're afraid of losing the changes you made, you could make a revese commit, making a commit to go back to a certain commit, and then recommit you changes one by one, reverse commit, then change directory, then commit, and so on.

`git revert HEAD~3`
change directory.
`git commit -a -f "directory fix1"`

`git revert HEAD~2`
change directory.
`git commit -a -f "directory fix2"`

`git revert HEAD~1`
change directory.
`git commit -a -f "directory fix3"`

Comment: how do i proceed to update old commits? any commands? if I revert to first commit and make the changes i'll lose other files.

Comment: The solution that uses `revert` produces 6 (!) new commits. All the needed changes can be operated in a single new commit, without reverting anything.

Comment: @axiac I agree, as I described at the beginning of my answer, Yet I suggested having revet commits to save the commits with just the change to the directory without worrying about the original commits.